# Error when declaring more than one KafkaTransactionManager

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka 2.8.4.

I created 2 versions of a producer to configure 2 producers with different values,
and declared the
KafkaTransactionManager to configure 2 producers with different values.
And we are using JPA. (Total 3 transaction managers)
I wanted to use JPA by default, so I used the following.

```
@Bean
@Primary
fun transactionManager(em: EntityManagerFactory): JpaTransactionManager {
    return JpaTransactionManager(em)
}
```

To use only kafka transactions, not JPA, I used the following.

```
@Transactional("kafkaStringTransactionManager")
fun send(topic: String, message: String) {
    kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message)
}
```

You will get an error like this

> No transaction is in process; possible solutions: run the template
> operation within the scope of a template.executeInTransaction()
> operation, start a transaction with @Transactional before invoking the
> template method, run in a transaction started by a listener container
> when consuming a record.

This works fine when there is only one kafkaTransactionManager,
but when there is more than one, there is a problem.
If I use the `executeInTransaction` method without using annotations, it works as I want, but is there any way to use annotations?

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same `ProducerFactory` for that `kafkaStringTransactionManager` and `kafkaTemplate`?

Comment: No, I'm using a different ProducerFactory.

Answer (score 1):

To make the `@Transactional` with a `KafkaTransactionManager` and `KafkaTemplate` working together, the same `ProducerFactory` must be configured on both `KafkaTransactionManager` and `KafkaTemplate`. The doc states that clearly in the beginning of transactions section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#using-kafkatransactionmanager.

> You must configure the `KafkaTemplate` to use the same `ProducerFactory` as the transaction manager.

**UPDATE**

So, the problem is here:

```
@Bean("createdMemberKafkaTransactionManager")
    fun createdMemberKafkaTransactionManager(): KafkaTransactionManager<String, CreatedMember> {
        return KafkaTransactionManager(createdMemberProducerFactory())
    }

 @Bean("createdMemberKafkaTemplate")
    fun createdMemberKafkaTemplate(): KafkaTemplate<String, CreatedMember> {
        return KafkaTemplate(createdMemberProducerFactory())
    }

  private fun createdMemberProducerFactory(): ProducerFactory<String, CreatedMember> {
        return DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(
            defaultConfigs().apply {
                this[ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG] = "create-member-${UUID.randomUUID()}"
            }
        )
    }
```

The `ProducerFactory` in the end is not a bean and therefore `KafkaTransactionManager` and `KafkaTemplate` gets different instances.

That's why a bean method references is an evil since it is not directly clear from a code if method we call is a bean method or not. The project can compile and even run, but it might be hard to determine the problem later on at runtime. Therefore better to use parameter injections instead and `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)`

Comment: Yes, I did the same. I'd appreciate it if you could check out my Github Repository when you have a chance. https://github.com/kdhyo/kafka-example

Comment: Your example is too complicated; see [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). However, see my comment on the [GitHub issue you opened](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2655#issuecomment-1511439010); it includes a working example.